# How to dial phone numbers which are contained in two line ListView

Tags: android, listview, phone-call

I am trying to populate a two line list with name and numbers.

I have finished this part, but i want to dial those numbers when clicked on particular items.

I know this method for single line list but i find it hard for two lines.

Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/vn6zDvu

```js
package com.example.tushar.twolinelist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private SimpleAdapter sa;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        HashMap<String, String> item;


        for (int
                     i = 0; i < nameandmubers.length; i++) {
            item = new
                    HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("line1",
                    nameandmubers[i][0]);
            item.put("line2",
                    nameandmubers[i][1]);
            list.add(item);
        }
        sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list1,
                new String[]{"line1", "line2"},
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});

        setListAdapter(sa);
       

    }

    private String[][] nameandmubers = {{"mehadi", "0123565"},
            {"sagor", "01615"}, {"ovi", "2356565"}, {"hamidul", "25341"},
            


    };


}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff1483d1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:id="@+id/text1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffb14d"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:id="@+id/text2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
  @Override 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
 { 
    String mynumber= //use something like a mutlidimensional array eg. String with value as 'position'
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(mynumber));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

It may help !.